# Fixing MTRR error in Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, kde, backtrack

I am getting this error is Backtrack 5 R3 using KDE,

Error setting MTRR (base=0x80000000 size=0x10000000 type = 1 inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

[Here is the X server log](http://pastebin.com/x6KrUfdu)

[and here is my MTRR Values](http://pastebin.com/pE2i3kVp)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had problems with

> /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d

It was missing. I booted though a live cd, and copied the **xorg.conf.d** in the collect path